# Asking for opinion or potential answer due to lack of official statement?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

There are some series that ended in midway, I mean unexpectedly in 1/2 season, for example [The Tomorrow People](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660734/). These series failed to explain the whole plot and remain a mystery.

There are also movies such as [The Last Airbender](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0938283/). Though there is a chance of part two, I don't think it's coming anymore.

These kinds of series and movies kept a lot of questions/plot unexplained for the next part/season. But there might not be a second season/part. Like in the TV-show Forever they kept the main plot unexplained and as the TV channel cancelled the season 2 those plots are unexplained forever. Similarly there are questions regarding The Last Airbender but part 2 may not happen and questions remain.

Sometimes after the cancellation directors answer the plot in their own way or writers share their thoughts behind to explain those plots. Like in the TV-show **Firefly** they made a movie to explain it after the cancellation of season 2. But sometimes they're not explained and remain a mystery forever.

Now my question is, there can be answered or unanswered plots for these kinds of series and movies, can questions be asked for opinion on plots for these kinds of series/movies? Will it be on-topic if I ask a question just to know the users' own version due to lack of an official statement? Or may be there is one official explanation that I don't know of?

Comment: You don't need to accept the answer that fast, though. I'm certainly not the only community member and I am not dictating the policy of this site either. Maybe someone else has something to add, too. Only 8 people have seen this question yet anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson :) but your points are correct. And informative enough to justify my query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually two different types of questions you describe at the end of your question, from which I think one category is on-topic while to other one isn't.

> Can questions be asked for opinion on plots for these kinds of series/movies? Will it be on-topic if I ask a question just to know the users' own version due to lack of an official statement?

I'm not sure this would be on-topic so much here. Just asking for someone's ungrounded personal opinion about how a show should or could have ended seems entirely opinion-based and would likely be closed as such. While it is true that in many question categories the answers are not entirely bound to authoritative sources and can as well be reasonably deduced and explained based on the movie/TV-show, if there is really no information from the series to ground any argumentation on, the answers will devolve into pure speculation only. And a question that actively encourages that seems bound to be classed as "primarily opinion-based".

> Or may be there is one official explanation that I don't know of?

This however seems like a valid question, as you said yourself there could very well be some explanation by the writers or maybe background information from the book it's based on or any other material. And in fact we had [questions like those](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21792/49) in the past already. Maybe the answer is really just *"no, there is no information, it stays a mystery"*, but then be it so.

You might also be able to nudge the latter, good, kind of question a bit into a direction where people could use some more reasoning and less hard references, by including something like *"or did I miss some evidence from the previous season that sheds some more light on this"* (maybe after presenting how much you already deduced from the show itself). This could encourage people to reason based on facts presented in the show, while still staying away from complete and utter speculation. But designing and answering such a question could be a walk on a tightrope. It often just comes down to picking the right words.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. Asking for answers from a production status seems very plausible and doable. Asking for answers based on *what someone thinks might have happened* seems off-topic.

Comment: Yep. If you can find an official source, that's one thing... asking for what would essentially amount to "fan fiction" is completely off topic.